# converting blob data column to varchar type for the whole table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with blob column in it. The blob data is of char type of length 8, I want to convert it to varchar of 8 bit length for the whole table (either by redefining the table structure or casting). However I don't want to lose any data previously stored in it.
I am using oracle-sql-developer.[image]
[image]

I want to permanently change the data type (not for only select statements).
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: And what did you try so far and what was the issue with your attempt?

Comment: I tried to add a new column of varchar2(8), and then set it using `UPDATE blobTable SET new_col = old_col; ` . It is throwing following error. `Error report -
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 5000, maximum: 4000)`

Comment: the `BLOB` column contain a string of characters ? what a strange thing to have. I mean normally you would use `CLOB` for that. I can provide you an example  how to do this, but you need to consider which characterset your database has, because for sure varchar2(8) maybe is not enough

Comment: yeah, the DB is already set by someone else. I too am thinking why it is set as blob. Anyway please provide me some resources on that.

Comment: I post my answer. If it servers your purpose, please upvote it and accept it. Any doubt over it, comment on the answer section.

Comment: *The blob data is of char type of length 8* - Then this is not true, because `Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 5000, maximum: 4000)`

Comment: Actually I am collecting the data from C prog, there also I am receiving the 8 bit data.

Answer (score 1):

Taking in consideration that `BLOB` should not be used for this purpose, one way to do it is to create a function to convert the blob into a clob ( which is a character string ).

To be able to insert a string into a BLOB column, I need to use `utl_cast_to_raw`

Let me show you

```
SQL> create table test_blob ( c1 number, c2 blob ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_blob values ( 1 , utl_cast_to_raw('AAAABBBB') ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test_blob ;

        C1
----------
C2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
4141414142424242
```

Now, we create a function to convert the BLOB into a CLOB

```
create or replace function blob_to_char (b blob)
return clob is
  v_clob    clob;
  n         number;
  v_start   pls_integer := 1;
  v_buffer  pls_integer := 32767;
  v_varchar varchar2(32767);
begin
  if (b is null) 
  then
    return null;
  end if;
  if (dbms_lob.getlength(b)=0) 
  then
    return empty_clob();
  end if;
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob,true);
  for i in 1..ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(b) / v_buffer)
  loop
    v_varchar := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(b, v_buffer, v_start));
    dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob, length(v_varchar), v_varchar);
    v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
  end loop;
RETURN v_clob;
end blob_to_char;
/
```

Once we have the function, let's check it

```
SQL> select blob_to_char(c2) from test_blob ;

BLOB_TO_CHAR(C2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAAABBBB
```

Now, we add a new column and we update the new column as varchar with the blob source column

```
SQL> alter table test_blob add c3 varchar2(8) ;

Table altered.

SQL> update test_blob set c3 = blob_to_char(c2) ;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test_blob ;

        C1
----------
C2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C3
----------------
         1
4141414142424242
AAAABBBB
```

Comment: It is throwing following error, `Error report -
ORA-12899: value too large for column ---- (actual: 21, maximum: 8);`

Comment: then you have more than 8 characters in your column, or you  are using multibyte characterset. Instead of varchar2(8), use varchar2(40). I would appreciate if you upvote the answer. Currently the problem is that your BLOB is larger than 8 characters, which was post in your original question.

Comment: I think there is some character encoding issue also. I am seeing special chars only on oracle-sql developer.

Comment: what do you mean by character encoding ?? the BLOB will not be shown as normal characters. Use `sqlplus` instead ( as I did ). Obviously, I have no idea what you have stored on those BLOB columns that you say contain strings. The function will only work as long as the content of the BLOB is reproducible as a set of strings. BTW, we are here to help, but I would appreciate if you upvote the answer to recognize that my answer is helping you. Thank you

Comment: Also using varchar2(40) now throws this error, `Error report -
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4999, maximum: 4000)`

Comment: run this that we can get the maximum lenght of this column and put the output in your question: `select max(dbms_lob.getlength(blob_column)) from table`

Comment: yeah one row has 5000 length blob , I have deleted that row. Now I can update the new column. However I am seeing square boxes in the data. In sqlplus when I select that new varchar column it showing blank/space. And if I select stmnt with cast_to_varchar2 (blob_field) it is showing "?????" in sqlplus. Do you know what may be the problem?